# Many linker errors for glfw.3lib when creating Vulkan developer environment

Tags: visual-studio, linker-errors, development-environment, glfw, vulkan

I followed all the directions on the VulkanSDK dev environment tutorial, I ran the starter code and got a ton of errors

**Starter Code**
[image]

**Output Code**

`Build started... 1>------ Build started: Project: VulkanTest, Configuration: Debug x64 ------ 1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library 1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_TranslateMessage referenced in function _glfwPlatformInit 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_TranslateMessage 1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DispatchMessageW referenced in function _glfwPlatformInit 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_DispatchMessageW 1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PeekMessageW referenced in function _glfwPlatformInit 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_PeekMessageW 1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegisterDeviceNotificationW referenced in function _glfwPlatformInit 1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_UnregisterDeviceNotification referenced in function _glfwPlatformTerminate 1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateWindowExW referenced in function _glfwPlatformInit 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateWindowExW 1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DestroyWindow referenced in function _glfwPlatformTerminate 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_DestroyWindow 1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ShowWindow referenced in function _glfwPlatformInit 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ShowWindow 1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ToUnicode referenced in function _glfwPlatformInit 1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_MapVirtualKeyW referenced in function _glfwPlatformInit 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_MapVirtualKeyW 1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SystemParametersInfoW referenced in function _glfwPlatformInit 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_SystemParametersInfoW 1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateDCW referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp 1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DeleteDC referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp 1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDeviceCaps referenced in function _glfwGetMonitorContentScaleWin32 1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDeviceGammaRamp referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp 1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetDeviceGammaRamp referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetGammaRamp 1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDC referenced in function _glfwGetMonitorContentScaleWin32 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDC 1>glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDC 1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ReleaseDC referenced in function _glfwGetMonitorContentScaleWin32 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ReleaseDC 1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ChangeDisplaySettingsExW referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetVideoModes 1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_EnumDisplaySettingsW referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetVideoMode 1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_EnumDisplaySettingsExW referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetMonitorPos 1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_EnumDisplayDevicesW referenced in function _glfwPollMonitorsWin32 1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetMonitorInfoW referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetMonitorWorkarea 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetMonitorInfoW 1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_EnumDisplayMonitors referenced in function _glfwPollMonitorsWin32 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateBitmap referenced in function createIcon 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateRectRgn referenced in function updateFramebufferTransparency 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DeleteObject referenced in function createIcon 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateDIBSection referenced in function createIcon 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_TrackMouseEvent referenced in function windowProc 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetMessageTime referenced in function windowProc 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SendMessageW referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowIcon 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PostMessageW referenced in function _glfwPlatformPostEmptyEvent 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_WaitMessage referenced in function _glfwPlatformWaitEvents 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DefWindowProcW referenced in function windowProc 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_UnregisterClassW referenced in function _glfwUnregisterWindowClassWin32 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegisterClassExW referenced in function _glfwRegisterWindowClassWin32 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetLayeredWindowAttributes referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetWindowOpacity 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetLayeredWindowAttributes referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowOpacity 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_FlashWindow referenced in function _glfwPlatformRequestWindowAttention 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_MoveWindow referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowAspectRatio 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetWindowPos referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowFloating 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetWindowPlacement referenced in function createNativeWindow 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetWindowPlacement referenced in function createNativeWindow 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_IsWindowVisible referenced in function _glfwPlatformWindowVisible 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_IsIconic referenced in function _glfwPlatformWindowIconified 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_BringWindowToTop referenced in function _glfwPlatformCreateWindow 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_IsZoomed referenced in function _glfwPlatformWindowMaximized 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_OpenClipboard referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetClipboardString 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CloseClipboard referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetClipboardString 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetClipboardData referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetClipboardString 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetClipboardData referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetClipboardString 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_EmptyClipboard referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetClipboardString 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetFocus referenced in function _glfwPlatformCreateWindow 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetActiveWindow referenced in function _glfwPlatformPollEvents 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetKeyState referenced in function _glfwPlatformPollEvents 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetCapture referenced in function windowProc 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ReleaseCapture referenced in function windowProc 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_MsgWaitForMultipleObjects referenced in function _glfwPlatformWaitEventsTimeout 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetSystemMetrics referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowIcon 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetForegroundWindow referenced in function _glfwPlatformCreateWindow 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetPropW referenced in function createNativeWindow 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetPropW referenced in function _glfwPlatformPollEvents 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RemovePropW referenced in function _glfwPlatformDestroyWindow 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetWindowTextW referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowTitle 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetClientRect referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetFramebufferSize 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetWindowRect referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowAspectRatio 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_AdjustWindowRectEx referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetWindowFrameSize 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetCursorPos referenced in function _glfwPlatformPollEvents 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetCursor referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetCursor 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetCursorPos referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetCursorPos 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ClientToScreen referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetWindowPos 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ScreenToClient referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetCursorPos 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_WindowFromPoint referenced in function cursorInContentArea 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ClipCursor referenced in function updateClipRect 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetRect referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetWindowFrameSize 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PtInRect referenced in function cursorInContentArea 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetWindowLongW referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetWindowOpacity 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetWindowLongW referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowMonitor 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetClassLongPtrW referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetWindowIcon 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_LoadCursorW referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetCursor 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DestroyIcon referenced in function _glfwPlatformDestroyCursor 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_LoadImageW referenced in function _glfwPlatformCreateStandardCursor 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateIconIndirect referenced in function createIcon 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_MonitorFromWindow referenced in function _glfwPlatformGetWindowContentScale 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetRawInputData referenced in function windowProc 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegisterRawInputDevices referenced in function _glfwPlatformSetRawMouseMotion 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DragQueryFileW referenced in function windowProc 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DragQueryPoint referenced in function windowProc 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DragFinish referenced in function windowProc 1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DragAcceptFiles referenced in function createNativeWindow 1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetRawInputDeviceInfoA referenced in function deviceCallback 1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetRawInputDeviceList referenced in function deviceCallback 1>glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ChoosePixelFormat referenced in function _glfwInitWGL 1>glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DescribePixelFormat referenced in function _glfwCreateContextWGL 1>glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetPixelFormat referenced in function _glfwCreateContextWGL 1>glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SwapBuffers referenced in function swapBuffersWGL 1>C:\Users\benja\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\VulkanTest\x64\Debug\VulkanTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 96 unresolved externals 1>Done building project "VulkanTest.vcxproj" -- FAILED. ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: The very first error tells you in the error message exactly what you need to do to fix it. Do so and see if the others go away. If they don't, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/62576.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) and please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the code. Paste the code.